# Replace InputParameter value from a claim in B2C custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have this tranformation claim:

```
  <ClaimsTransformation Id="ComparePasswordResetOnWithCurrentDateTime" TransformationMethod="DateTimeComparison">
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="currentDateTime" TransformationClaimType="firstDateTime" />
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_passwordResetOn" TransformationClaimType="secondDateTime" />
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
      <InputParameter Id="operator" DataType="string" Value="earlier than" />
      <!--Deom Action Required: Change the time span according to 60 or 90 days (in seconds)-->
      <InputParameter Id="timeSpanInSeconds" DataType="int" Value="-80" />
    </InputParameters>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isPasswordResetOnGreaterThanNow" TransformationClaimType="result" />
    </OutputClaims>      
  </ClaimsTransformation>
```

And I need to change the `timeSpanInSeconds` from `-80` to a value from an claim. Ultimately this claim will be a custom attribute.

Is it possible to achieve this in custom policy?

I've tried to replace  `<InputParameter Id="timeSpanInSeconds" DataType="int" Value="-80" />` with   `<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_timeSpanInSeconds" />` but apparentry I can't use a InputClaim as an InputParameter.